# Set Array Items in Method Parameter

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

I would like to set the items in an array of Strings in the parameter of a method.

So if I have an array, `public String[] messages;`

Then I have a method, 
`public void setMessages()`,

I want to be able to use the parameters to set the items in the array, like this:

```
public void setMessages(String[] messages) {
   this.messages = messages;
}

setMessages("Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3");
```

And then the array has those three strings in it. How could I do something like this, because that obviously doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setMessages` method accepts an array and not three `String` parameters as mentioned here:

```
public void setMessages(String[] messages)
```

So you need to pass an array to it. Simply replace

```
setMessages("Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3");
```

with

```
setMessages(new String[] {"Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3"});
```

Comment: +1 I like new String[]{} better than varargs. I recently got burned with varargs causing an ambiguous signature.

Answer (score -1):

Change your method signature to accept `messages` as a variable-length argument, or vararg for short.

```
public void setMessages(String... messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}
```

What are [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)?

- They are equivalent to an array of the same type (so above, you still have a `String[]`).
- They allow any arbitrary number of values to be placed into it.
- They do not require the caller to create a new instance of an array to pass in (which would look like this):

  ```
   setMessages(new String[] {"Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3"});
  ```